# How to upload a Youtube video via the API using an OAuth2 Access Token (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, api, upload, youtube

I'm a seasoned .NET developer and i'm making a video uploader app that only needs to work with 2 or 3 accounts. Using 1 account as my test case i've authorised my app with it, got my authorization key back and I now have an access+refresh token.

Getting to this stage I now realise I have no idea how to upload a video with my access token (I know i'll probably need to refresh it by the time this is answered) - can anyone help? I can't find any documentation about using the Youtube .NET client libraries (e.g. YouTubeRequestSettings, YouTubeRequest etc.) to do this - all help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you done a google search..? there is an example out there on how to do this.. you need to 
What you are trying to do requires using asynchronous upload. A complete example showing how to use the ResumableUploader component and the AsyncOperationCompleted/AsyncOperationProgress events is included in the .NET client library and available at http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fclients%2Fcs%2Fsamples%2FYouTubeUploader%2FYouTubeUploader

Comment: @DJKRAZE - It's impressive that you're trying to be both helpful and insulting at the same time - that link doesn't use an OAuth key anywhere, if you look at the last method in the YoutubeUploader it uses the username and password for the Youtube account - which is against recommended best practice (hence my attempts to use OAuth!)

If you'd do me the honour of removing your down vote I might get some more eyes on my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this out by trial and error - the disjointed Youtube API documentation really didn't help matters!

AuthSub is deprecated, if you go through the hassle of getting an OAuth2 key (which is quite well described in the documentation) you can upload videos using it.

To do so just use the access_token in place of the authsub key in the 'YoutubeRequestSettings' object - as in the below sample:

```
string myDeveloperKey = "Your developer key here";
string myOAuthKey = "The OAuth key for the target user's account here";

YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("My Uploader App Name", myDeveloperKey, myOAuthKey); // The documentation for this method implies it only accepts an authSub key - it works if you pass your OAuth key

YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

Video newVideo = new Video();

newVideo.Title = "Test Video - ignore me";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "test 1 , test 2";

newVideo.Description = "test 3 test 4";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("tag 1, tag 2", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
newVideo.Private = true; // Make this video private as it's a test

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);

newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(@"C:\MyTestVideo.mov", "video/quicktime");

Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```